# Will Microsofts SHA-1 deprecation affect web service clients based on Microsoft technology

Tags: .net, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, sha1

In the [Technet blog about Microsoft's SHA-1 deprecation policy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2013/11/12/sha1-deprecation-policy.aspx) I read the following quote:

*For SSL certificates, Windows will stop accepting SHA1 end-entity certificates by 1 January 2017. This means any time valid SHA1 SSL certificates must be replaced with a SHA2 equivalent by 1 January 2017.*

To me it is not 100% clear what is affected. I suppose that IE/Edge won't accept any SSL connections with SHA-1 certificates anymore. But what about web services? Will Web Service clients using Microsoft Libraries and Frameworks (e.g. .NET) not be able to call HTTPS web services that still use SHA-1 anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the policy affects all Microsoft products that use CryptoAPI for certificate validation. This includes web services and .NET.